# Why is this method undefined if it's an attribute of my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access the field of a object.  Here is my code:

```
<% if @statuses %>
      <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
        <div class="well">
          <%= status.content %>
          <br></br>

          <%= user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id]) %>
          <br></br>

          <% @profile_user = User.find(status.tag_list).first %>
          <%= link_to @profile_user.profile_name, user_profile_path(@profile_user.profile_name) %>


          <br></br>
          <%= status.user.full_name %>
          <hr />
          <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at), status_path(status) %> ago
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end%>
```

at this line:

```
<%= link_to @profile_user.profile_name, user_profile_path(@profile_user.profile_name) %>
```

I get this error message:

```
undefined method `profile_name' for #< Array:0x007fe265c40410>
```

This is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
      rolify
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    validates :first_name, presence: true

    validates :last_name, presence: true

    validates :profile_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true,
                              format: {
                                with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/,
                                message: 'Must be formatted correctly'
                              }

    has_many :statuses

      def full_name
        first_name + " " + last_name
      end

      def gravatar_url
        stripped_email = email.strip
        downcased_email =stripped_email.downcase
        hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(downcased_email)

        "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
      end

    end
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class):

```
Person.find([1])     # returns an array for the object with ID = 1
```

Presumably, `status.tag_list` is an array, so when you pass it to `User#find`, you're getting an array back in response. This array doesn't have a `profile_name` method, which is why you're seeing a `NoMethodError`.

I can't be sure what your intentions are here, so either:

- pass a specific ID to `User#find` in order to get a single `User` back in response
- use first/last to pull a specific user out of your call to `User#find`. Something like, `@profile_user = User.find(status.tag_list).first`
- iterate over the array in `@profile_user` when rendering the links, in case you're actually expecting multiple `User`s.

Comment: this makes the first part of the failing line work but the user_profile_path(@profile_user.profile_name) is still failing with the error
 undefined method `profile_name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It'd help to see your updated code and/or your model, but my guess is that you should change `user_profile_path(@profile_user.profile_name)` to `user_profile_path(@profile_user)`

Comment: That didn't work for me.  For some reason, the user_profile_path(@profile_user) is causing the route to not work at all.  If i delete the entire line of code, it allows me to render the page i'm trying to link too if i manually type in the url.  Otherwise i get the nil:NIlClass error

Comment: It sounds like your call to `User#find` is returning `nil` for some reason. As I said, I'd have to see your updated code in order to offer any additional assistance. You may want to open a separate question for that problem as it's unrelated to your original question.

Comment: thanks I added my user model.  I will open a second question as well.

Comment: You should include the changes you made to your view. Also, if you do open a new question - and you're satisfied with my answer to your original question - you should mark this one answered.

Comment: Your answer was informative but I still have a nil error and i can't access the attribute i need so I'm going to leave this unanswered.  My view is updated

Comment: I don't see where the view has changed at all... it looks like you're still passing an array to `User#find`.

Comment: added .first to my view

Comment: OK - so your original problem has been solved. Now, you need to figure out what's wrong with that query. It could be a problem with your data (is `status.tag_list` empty? if not, does it contain valid User ids?) or a problem with your association (would need to see the Status model and your schema), etc.

Comment: what is happening is the route is being succesfully created (the profile_name is being pulled and appended to the url correctly) but for some reason the page doesn't load.  Instead the nil error.  Even stranger if I delete the link_to line of code we're working with, those routes work again and the page will load