# Link_to is somehow destroying my route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use `link_to` in my web application:

```
<% if @statuses %>
  <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
    <div class="well">
      <%= status.content %>
      <br></br>
      <% @profile_user = User.find(status.tag_list).first %>
      <%= @profile_user%>

      <%= link_to @profile_user.profile_name, user_profile_url(@profile_user) %>

      <br></br>
      <%= status.user.full_name %>
      <hr />
      <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at), status_path(status) %> ago
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end%>
```

This line of code causes an error:

```
<%= link_to @profile_user.profile_name, user_profile_url(@profile_user) %>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
undefined method `profile_name' for nil:NilClass
```

but my route is seemingly working.  The route should be: `mywebsite.com/profile_name`.

I get an error with my current code.  If I delete the line that is problematic I can manually enter the URL that I am trying to access and the page will render with no problem.

Comment: try iteration (`x.each do |y|`) in rails console. you'll be able to see what is problem. Probably one of  the `User.find` queries returns nil, because of it can't find any record with `status.tag_list`.

Comment: Can you show your controller where you actually define @profile_user?  Essentially @profile_user is not set when you are calling it.  You need to define it in the associated controller action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this method undefined if it's an attribute of my model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447128/why-is-this-method-undefined-if-its-an-attribute-of-my-model)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a bit strange:

```
User.find(status.tag_list)
```

The find method will look for a user with a matching id, are you sure the method tag_list on the status object will return a user id?